# fullscreen link background

Tags: jquery, background, webkit, fullscreen, rotator

So, making this simple random fullscreen bg image page, rotator and min.js work, 
Im sure there are other ways to do that, now Im trying to make the whole page a link that simply reloads the page, so that I get another random image.
Ive searched for ways to make the rotator div a link, css solutions- spans and hidden displays, but I certainly am not understanding which is appropriate, no luck getting anything to work. any suggestions are much appreciated,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    * {  margin: 0; padding: 0; }

    html { 
        background: url(images/rotator.php), url(grey.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed ; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rotator").click(function(){
window.location.reload(true);});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rotator"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alright, so no luck with the jquery way, i did do this,

```
<div style="width:800px;height:800px;position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;" id="rotator" onclick = "window.location.refresh()"></div>
```

Not ideal, but gets the behavior I want, now to change the cursor so people know its a link,

Comment: add this to the css `cursor:pointer`

Answer (score 0):

inside `<div id="rotator">` try putting `<a href="" style='display:block;height:100%;width:100%'></a>`

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery:

```
$("#rotator").click(function(){
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```

It adds a click() event to the div with the id of #rotator, effectively making it a giant link.  The result of the click is a refresh.

You can easily change the mouse cursor with CSS:

```
#rotator {cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Updated with your suggestion, feel like I'm missing something basic,

Comment: I did, tested with an alert mssg, I found a way that will work, although not ideally, Ill post it, just need to find a way to change the cursor, bout to go research. thanks